# What is on the DVD Edition of Ubuntu?

Tags: release-management

Just curious, because Google isn't coming up with anything and Ubuntu.com is hardly descriptive; but what is the difference between Ubuntu CD .iso and the DVD .iso? What's on the DVD that isn't on the CD?

Comment: Is there a way to suggest additional packages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### For 11.04 and earlier

The DVD contains all language packs, plus a few additional applications.

From http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/downloadmirrors#dvd:

> Don't be confused, even though DVDs
>   can hold far more data than the
>   typical Ubuntu CD, the main benefit of
>   the DVD downloads is to get access to
>   all of the available language packs.
>   Most people will be fine with the
>   standard CD installer. There are fewer
>   download locations for the DVD images
>   and this list is updated less
>   frequently than for the CD images.

Comment: But why then do I see "Downloading language packs" when installing from DVD. I am talking about 14.04 LTS.

Comment: please update the 404 link

Answer (score 30):

#### 11.10 and newer

The DVD contains [extra software](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download#dvd):

> The new DVD image is an extension of our current CD image to include all the language packs and some other useful applications, such as Inkscape, GIMP, Pitivi, and a more complete LibreOffice suite. All the packages that used to be on the DVD are still available from the archive.

The list of extra packages is available in this [seed file](http://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.precise/dvd), and here's the [full manifest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/dvd/current/precise-dvd-amd64.manifest).

Here are some of the major packages that are probably the most interesting for end users, (there are many more listed in the file so here are the highlights):

More drivers:

- NVIDIA and ATI Drivers
- bcmwl-kernel-source

Extra desktop Packages:

- XChat GNOME (IRC client)
- More complete LibreOffice suite
- nautilus-gksu
- GIMP (Image editor)
- Inkscape (Vector image editor)
- vim-tiny and vim-gnome (Text editor)
- Liferea (RSS reader)
- Pitivi (Video editor)
- openprinting-ppds-extra (More PPDs for more printer support)
- Screem (HTML editor)
- Iced Tea plugin (Java)

Other:

- Flac command line tools
- More dictionaries
- A bunch of documentation packages (monodoc, ubuntu-faqguide, basic HOWTOs from LDP, GIMP manuals)
- The following language packs: en es xh pt de fr
- Localization files and fonts

More about seeds here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SeedManagement

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers w/ the alternate area text, here's a list of the files on the i386 version of Maverick:

http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/maverick/release/ubuntu-10.10-dvd-i386.list

Answer (score 4):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

> DVD downloads
>
> Don't be confused, even though DVDs
> can hold far more data than the
> typical Ubuntu CD, the main benefit of
> the DVD downloads is to get access to
> all of the available language packs.
> Most people will be fine with the
> standard CD installer. There are fewer
> download locations for the DVD images
> and this list is updated less
> frequently than for the CD images.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the answer to your question](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads): Download the DVD edition. On DVD edition you can have access to all the available language packs.