# What extra packages are available on the DVD that are not on the CD?

Tags: 11.10, release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is on the DVD Edition of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10844/what-is-on-the-dvd-edition-of-ubuntu)

I read in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/TechnicalOverview/Beta1) that there is a new DVD release of Ubuntu with extra packages not found on the CD:

> With 11.10 Beta 1, we're introducing a revised smaller DVD based on community feedback over the last few cycles. This is in addition to the traditional CD which remains available. This new DVD has a more manageable size of 1.5G. The new DVD image is an extension of our current CD image to include all the language packs and some other useful applications, such as Inkscape, GIMP, Pitivi, and a more complete LibreOffice suite. All the packages that used to be on the DVD are still available from the archive.

Were can I find the complete list of changes between the DVD and CD?