# Will the mini DVD iso include the media codecs and Ubuntu restricted extras?

Tags: 11.10

I am currently torn between the regular CD iso and the mini DVD iso which I read will include GIMP, Pitivi etc. I will like to know the list of apps and codecs included in the mini DVD iso. 
Most of my friends can't try Ubuntu because they just don't want to go through the hussle of installing codecs and stuff so the mini DVD ,if it includes the media codecs and apps like VLC will be great for newbies.

Comment: Installing codecs hasn't been a hassle for years now.  These days when you try to play a file that needs one, you get a pop up asking if you want to download it.  Click yes, and you're done.

Comment: Easy if you have access to the internet but frustrating if you don't. Lol...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of included apps is here:

- [What is on the DVD Edition of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10844/what-is-on-the-dvd-edition-of-ubuntu)

Like the CD, the codecs need to be installed during installationThe reason they're not included as installed by default is [detailed here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) (it's not a size issue).

However during the installation there is a simple checkbox that users can click to have the codecs installed during the installation.