# Why doesn't Ubuntu make a DVD iso?

Tags: development, iso

I mean, I think it might be kind of cool if they made a bigger installation media with more applications, maybe include various other environment( okay, probably not going to do that but as it seems you are downsizing your based off of distros).  You might also have like option bundles like say a security bundle with nmap or something like that or perhaps a artsy one with gimp and other multimedia creation apps.  Just wondering?

Answer (score 9):

DVD releases can be found in cdimage.ubuntu.com:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/release/

This question outlines the differences between what is on the CD and DVD:

- [What is on the DVD Edition of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10844/what-is-on-the-dvd-edition-of-ubuntu)

The "bundles" you mention could be fulfilled by the "variants", such as kubuntu, Ubuntu Studio (artsy one as you mention)! and others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a distro that bases itself on security then there are many.  Backtrack being one of the more famous and used by many sys admins to check the overall security of their networks.  Your options bundles are all over the internet to download rather then trying to pick out which ones might be best to fit on a dvd for distribution.  This is the basis of the overall Open Source concept, being able to start with a good working distribution and building on that to fit an individuals needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the sort of question anyone here can answer.  It'd fit much better in [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/), where speculative questions and answers are welcome and fun, and can even run into dozens or even hundreds of posts.

Having said that, though, I'll add that I don't see a real advantage to Ubuntu producing special option bundles, at least not yet.  I've been using Linux and Ubuntu less than a year, but even I know how to download and install the special apps I need in order to make Ubuntu be what I want it to be.  (And how to find very specialized distros, too, if I really want such.)