# Why is the 11.10 ISO so much larger than the 11.04 one?

Tags: dvd, release-management, versions

Wanted to download Ubuntu and I just saw that `ubuntu-11.04-dvd-amd64.iso` is 4GB while the `ubuntu-11.10-dvd-amd64.iso` is only 1.5GB.

Why the difference in size? Is there something missing form 11.10?

If yes, what's the release number with "the most complete set of applications"?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60969/18887) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10844/what-is-on-the-dvd-edition-of-ubuntu), 11.10 has extra packages on the DVD versions. 11.04 and earlier had additional language packs with a few extra software in the DVD versions.

Look at the file size differences at the [Ubuntu Releases page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/) gives information that

- [11.04 Natty](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/release/) is 4 GB
- [11.10 Oneiric](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.10/release/) is 1.5 GB
- [12.04 Precise Beta 1](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/beta-1/) is 1.5 GB

You can view the extra packages by viewing the seed files of the DVD versions of Natty, Oneiric and Precise to see and make a better decision of which would suit you best.

- [11.04 Natty DVD seed file](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.natty/dvd)
- [11.10 Oneiric DVD seed file](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.oneiric/dvd)
- [12.04 Precise Beta 1 Seed file](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.precise/dvd)

Just remember, not everything bigger is better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why the smaller size?

This was the result of [a UDS discussion](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-o-great-cd-debate). Here's [an announcement Allison posted](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-June/033418.html). Basically, 1.5G is bigger enough to be useful, and not so big that it takes forever to download.

The smaller size means less of a big jump from the 700MB CD (which we are outgrowing), with less impact on mirrors (disk space and bandwidth), and means we are still forced to carefully pick what we want on the images.

Answer (score -1):

A lot was changed from 11.04 to 11.10. The biggest change was that classic Gnome was removed as a fallback option to Unity. Also, PiTiVi was removed as a video editor and not replaced. Thunderbird was put in place of Evolution.

Of course, these were only removed from the default disk, not from the repositories, so "the most complete set of applications" doesn't really make sense as a question.

For example, if you got an 11.04 Ubuntu disk, you'd get a copy of PiTiVi with it. But then there would be updates to get it to the latest version which you'd want to download. You might as well have got 11.10, and done "apt-get install pitivi" to start with!