# Is there a wubi installer for the ubuntu DVD version?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, dvd

These days my heart pumps more blood to itself because of Ubuntu 12.04 release. I would like to download it about two or three days later.we know there is a wubi for the cd version included. I want to know, is there a wubi installer for the Ubuntu DVD version? and what will be the size of the dvd image? 4.7GB?

Comment: I don't think wubi is included with 12.04 at all. Anyway, why would one need it on a DVD?

Comment: Because I usually install it using it(easy to install and backup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wubi is not yet available for dvd version, and It is difficault to predict the size of ubuntu DVD before its release :)

EDit: As per [this page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/dvd/current/)

The current size of 12.04 dvd is

32 bit : 1.5 GB

64 bit : 1.6 GB

Linked Question

[What is on the DVD Edition of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10844/what-is-on-the-dvd-edition-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Wubi has never been able to install from the DVD ISO. From release 12.04, Wubi won't install from CD either. You'll only be able to use the boot helper.

The only supported way to install inside Windows in 12.04 will be running wubi.exe standalone. See [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-March/034970.html) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/975251) for more info.