# can ubuntu 12.10 be installed using wubi

Tags: 12.10

can ubuntu 12.10 be installed using wubi ? because in ubuntu 12.04 wubi is disabled ! ^^

in ubuntu 12.04 there is no option to install inside windows

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu 12.10 with Wubi. I just did, a couple of days ago.

Double-clicking the DVD drive didn't seem to work, so I downloaded the Wubi app from Ubuntu website separately, and ran it. It detected the disk, extracted files and started the installer. Not sure if it was redundant, either way it worked. Hope this helps.

Edit: Found https://askubuntu.com/a/124828/114038 which confirms that 12.04+ requires you to use the standalone Wubi.exe, as I did.