# Whats the difference between the 12.04 CD and DVD versions?

Tags: 12.04, livedvd

I found myself in confusion when I saw a [CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) version and a [DVD](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/dvd/current/) version of the Ubuntu 12.04. I once thought that DVD will include both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, but, actually DVD version also asked me to choose between the two architectures... Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CD includes typical Ubuntu installation, DVD provides extra codecs, extra software etc. out-of-the-box.

You can use CD image and after installation set all the nesecary codecs and extras by hand, or use DVD and it will preinstall everything there is.

I recommend CD image !

Comment: And for the simple reason that the CD image omits necessary codecs and extras, I recommend the DVD image.

But if you use the CD image, you can install them later with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Does the CD also omit X server?

Answer (score 4):

No, the DVD is not multi-architecture.  It simply includes more packages.  It's mainly intended to be the desktop edition CD plus all the stuff we would add to that if only the laws of physics (the CD size limit) didn't get in our way: for instance, it includes Thunderbird, the IcedTea Java web browser plugin, the GIMP image editor, Inkscape, the PiTiVi audio/video editor, and various others.

See also:

- [What is on the DVD Edition of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10844/what-is-on-the-dvd-edition-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu DVD includes all the language packs and some other useful applications, such as Inkscape, GIMP, Pitivi, plus a more complete LibreOffice suite.

The main purpose of DVD version is to provide all languages support. If you don't need that then CD version is recommended as you can download the apps from Ubuntu Software Center.

All this information is present at 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 2):

I ran a 'diff -y' on the manifests for the CD and the DVD images ( ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.manifest and ubuntu-12.04-dvd-i386.manifest ) and it essentially confirms the last two answers of 'Colin Watson' and 'Zeal Kaiser'.

Of course there are a few more apps included than listed in the two previous answers ( for example 'vim' and 'emacs' as well as 'jre' on so on. The rest are various language packs, locales ( for firfox for example ) and offline help systems ( in four languages for gimp ) and so on.

I though about dumping the output here BUT I don't think it is appropriate. 
Simply download the manifests for the the CD and the DVD versions, do a diff -y ( or use 'meld' or 'xxdiff' ) )and you'll get the hard facts.

For example you can download the DVD manifest at

http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/ubuntu-cdimage/releases/precise/release/

the CD manifest you could get at

http://nl.releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Hope this helps!