# Does remmina come with Ubuntu 12.04 CD?

Tags: 12.04, remmina

I want to try Ubuntu 12.04 and test remmina RDP viewer (I hear it is a good one). However I am in no mood to download the DVD. Does remmina come in the CD download? Can someone confirm?

PS: I do not have an internet connection on the system I need to try it on - just an internal network.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it Does you can take a look here [Mentioning the remmina package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=remmina+) and listed here as [Remmina in Ubuntu-Desktop packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-desktop) .Screenshots would help

[image]

And for Adding Configuration

[image]

For the DVD and CD difference you can refer here

[Whats the difference between the 12.04 CD and DVD versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125998/whats-the-difference-between-the-12-04-cd-and-dvd-versions)

[What is on the DVD Edition of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10844/what-is-on-the-dvd-edition-of-ubuntu)

Comment: and difference between CD/DVD download is only limited to language packs. DVD will have language packs as CD won't. Apps are same in both.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) BTW, I did not really need screenshots. They are available all over :P SE is saying I can accept answer in 2 minutes. What does that mean?

Comment: @Web-E Thanks for telling that. I did not know!

Comment: yes Web-E is right , i edited the answer providing more info about the DVD contents. Thanks.