# where can I download ubuntu 13.04 DVD image (not CD image)

Tags: installation, 13.04, 64-bit, iso, dvd

I want to install 64-bit ubuntu 13.04, but cannot find a DVD image.  I don't want a CD image, because it will be missing things I want (always happens).

But I cannot find such an image, except ubuntustudio, which has some completely different window manager that I don't recognize.

I have searched and looked for 2 hours already.  So where did they hide it?

Comment: I don't think there is any distinct DVD image vs. CD image for the basic Ubuntu install. The standard desktop image (`ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso`) is now a DVD image only by virtue of the fact that it is bigger than 700MB, and so won't fit on a standard CD.

Comment: DVD ISO's not available for Ubuntu 13.04 and they havent hide it because they are not released by Ubuntu :P

Comment: see differences here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125998/whats-the-difference-between-the-12-04-cd-and-dvd-versions

Comment: you may want to read, [iso image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image)

Comment: you might also consider, [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 1):

Actually Ubuntu previously released its ISO's in DVD  in its alternate Ubuntu downloads but due to some reasons the project has been stopped and for Ubuntu 13.04 the   download of DVD wasnt available.

The only choice you have for Ubuntu 13.04 is it's LIVE ISO only. if you want it you can get it from Official Ubuntu site.

if you still want a Ubuntu DVD and wont care about the version means I can suggest you to go for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , its still having the  download support. If you want , you can get from

**for 32-bit**

http://mirror.eftel.com/ubuntu-dvd/12.04.3/release/ubuntu-12.04.3-dvd-i386.iso

**for 64-bit**

http://mirror.eftel.com/ubuntu-dvd/12.04.3/release/ubuntu-12.04.3-dvd-amd64.iso

Answer (score 0):

Try http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/

You probably want `ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

When you install that you will have a desktop with most of the stuff you probably want. Anything else you can get from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: My friend he wants a DVD ISO , But you have mentioned desktop CD ISO for a 64-bit PC. :)

Comment: That is a DVD iso - must be, it is bigger than 700MB.

Comment: No My friend , Ubuntu ISO has already crossed 700 MB from  few past releases and still we are saying it as CD ISO and indeed we need a DVD to burn.

Comment: What do you expect a DVD release to have that this iso does not? This iso is what Ubuntu releases.

Comment: I have mentioned some links that are DVD links and for Ubuntu 12.04 , because Ubuntu 13.04 not have any dvd iso;s released by Ubuntu.