# Difference between ubuntu desktop.iso version and dvd.iso version?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is on the DVD Edition of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10844/what-is-on-the-dvd-edition-of-ubuntu)

Can anyone tell me what the basic difference between the two is ? and what would you recommend for a beginner ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the only difference between the two is that the DVD iso's have more language packs. They may also have more drivers but I can't say. I would recommend the default .iso which you can download from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Simply "Choose your flavour" Either 64 Bit or 32 Bit depending on your system and then proceed to create a live CD or live USB and then install. And the instructions for doing so can be found here if you do not already know: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop

If there is anything missing from the default .iso you can simply install them later, but most likely it is just the language packs. However all versions of Ubuntu newer then 12.04.XX will be too big to fit on a Cd so you will be required to create a live DVD or a live USB, as the .iso will be too big to fit on a single CD.